# SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS Error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, collation

Getting this error when copying views from one database to another:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "French_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

The database uses the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation, and all the tables use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, but I am getting the above error. The original data is coming from a progress database that has a `french_ci` collation.

Is it possible that the data is stored as French_cI. How can I fix this issue (T-SQL or other) without adding a collation manually to each view column?

Comment: How are you copying your views? Can you share the view definition of one of them?

Comment: We were importing data and table definitions using the Select * into table from progress db table, which was copying the schema definition which had its collation set to French_CI. We have stopped doing that.

Comment: Basically I wrote a SQL query to convert every column in tables in DB to the Latin1 collation